# How to align icons vertically or horizontally when window size varies

Tags: html, css

**When web page is narrow [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42x1K.png) image is accepted. When page is wide [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3RUu.png) image is accepted. But [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXuvx.png) image is not accepted** 
Consider a text in left and icons in right or web page

How can we avoid the [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXuvx.png) situation using css or any frontend technique?

[image: Acceptance]

[image: Acceptance]

[image: Not Acceptance]

Adding html code:

```html
<div>
  <span width='80%'>Text here</span>
  <span width='20%'>icon1,icon2,icon3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: add your HTML Code

Comment: use media query in css. that's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest bet here is to go with flexbox:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 150px) {
  #container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* unrelated to the solution */

#container img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32"/>
</div>
```

Try [resizing the window on Codepen](https://codepen.io/iTayGNR/pen/bOwjxX)  to see the change at `150px`.